# Netbeans-PHPUnit "No tests executed" error

Tags: php, netbeans, phpunit, pear, netbeans-7.3

I am newbie to any kind of testing. I just installed pear and PHPUnit using this [doc](http://kubyshkin.ru/posts/phpunit-on-mac-os-x-snow-leopard-10-6.html). I use netbeans 7.3.1. I also installed `skeletongenerator` running this command : `pear install phpunit/PHPUnit_SkeletonGenerator`.

I Followed the steps listed in this [testing with PHPUnit](https://netbeans.org/kb/docs/php/phpunit.html#installing-phpunit) to integrate PHPUnit to netbeans.
As described in `Installing PHPUnit` section of that doc, by clicking `search` button under `Netbeans->preferences->unit testing` my netbeans recognizes PHPUnit installation.

I followed all the steps to add sample `Calculator` project and generate test class. I did that. But when I run the tests by right clicking Calculator.php file and selecting `Test` I get following result.

[image]

Output window shows nothing useful :

[image]

I have no idea of what can be the problem and how to solve that.

**Few doubts that may be causing the above problem :**
What should I add in `Global include path` under `Netbeans->preferences->general`?
Do I need to add `require_once` statement in Calculator.php file?
Do I need to create php projects under some particular folder only or is it immaterial where I place projects?
How do I check that PHPUnit is installed properly and is working?

There can be many other symptoms that I am not even able to think of.

Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Solved by adding below line to `Calculatortest.php` file.

```
require_once dirname(__FILE__) . '/../Calculator.php';
```

The test class is placed in a subdirectory, so I needed to declare the path relative to the Calculator.php.

Also, I had to change php.ini file so that errors are displayed in case there are.
I set following variables in php.ini.

```
error_reporting  =  E_ALL | E_STRICT
display_errors = On
```

Answer (score 1):

I had suffered the same problem. However, perseverance paid.

1) Create the sample project using NB samples.

2) The directory structure should be:

- Source Files

  - Calculato.php
- Test Files
- Include Path

3) Right click on Calculator.php and choose Tools > Create Tests

4) Add `require_once '../src/Calculator.php';` immediately after the top `<?php`

5) Select `Calculator.php` and select `Test`

It worked for me. Let me know if it works for you. I hope, your configuration is ok.